# Fast hamming distance function in Julia that returns a distance matrix

Tags: performance, julia

I would like to use `Julia` to compute the hamming distance on a very large dataset.
I need to get back a distance matrix between rows in order to run further analysis on this matrix.

For my purposes, it is useful that the data are stored in a DataFrame type.

```
using DataFrames
```

The data looks something like this

```
a = [1 0 1 0 ; 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 1]

df = convert(DataFrame, a);

nrows = size(df, 1)
ncols = size(df, 2)
```

I made a function in `Julia`

```
function hamjulia(df)

    nrows = size(df, 1)
    ncols = size(df, 2)
    m, n = nrows, nrows
    A = fill(0, (m, n))

    for i in 1:nrows
    for k in 1:nrows
        
        v = 0
        for j in 1:ncols
            if df[i,j] != df[k,j]
            v += 1
            end
        end
        A[i,k] = v
    end
    end
    return A
end

p = hamjulia(df)
p
```

My issue is that this code is super slow compared to some R packages. For instance, when I compared this function to the `rdist` package, `rdist(df, metric = 'hamming')`, `R` is faster.

How could I make this code really efficient? Especially that I would need to run it on a very large dataframe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have three areas of suggestions below. Here's a modified version of your code that implements these suggestions:

```
# For memory safety, restrict type to Matrix due to the use of @inbounds below.
function ham(df::Matrix)
    nrows, ncols = size(df)
    A = fill(0, ncols, ncols)
    for j in 1:ncols, i in j+1:ncols
        v = 0
        for k in 1:nrows
            v += @inbounds (df[k, i] != df[k, j])
        end
        A[i, j] = A[j, i] = v
    end
    return A
end

ham(df::DataFrame) = ham(convert(Matrix, df))
```

---

**1. Write code for column-major arrays.**

Julia is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) (and packages like DataFrames.jl conform with this by storing data in columns), so when performance is important, you should iterate through the rows of a column. For example, when iterating through an array `A[x, y, z]`, the leftmost index `x` should be changing the most rapidly. Looking at the innermost loop in your code,

```
for j in 1:ncols
    if df[i,j] != df[k,j]
    v += 1
    end
end
```

notice that it is iterating through the columns of a row instead (i.e., `j` is changing most rapidly in `df[i,j]`). To get a free performance boost, rewrite the code to exchange the roles of columns and rows. The data will also need to be transposed. (Note that R is also column-major.)

Julia documentation: [memory order](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-column-major).

---

**2. In performance-critical loops, annotate `@inbounds` where possible.**

In the modified code I gave, the array access in the innermost loop is annotated with [`@inbounds`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@inbounds) to disable bounds checking. This gives a speedup in large part because it allows compiler to [automatically vectorize](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.SimdLoop.@simd) the loop.

Only use `@inbounds` if you are certain that out-of-bounds access is impossible; in our case, we cannot guarantee this for custom types, so we restrict the input type to a `Matrix` (an alias for `Array{T,2} where T`) to ensure that `df[k, i]` and `df[k, j]` are always in bounds. Like so:

```
function ham(df::Matrix)
    [...]
    for k in 1:nrows
        v += @inbounds (df[k, i] != df[k, j])
    end
    [...]
end
```

If `@inbounds` is not used, I would not restrict the input type and would instead leave it generic.

Julia documentation: [performance annotations](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-annotations).

---

**3. Beware of type instability.**

For performant code, functions should be type stable, meaning that given an input type, the output type can be inferred during compilation. Similarly, variables used within a function should be type stable.

As noted in its documentation, [`DataFrame`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/types/#DataFrames.DataFrame) columns are not type stable! That is, the type of a `DataFrame` does not contain information about the types of its columns; in fact, the `DataFrame` type is not parametric, so the type contains *no* information other than that it is a `DataFrame`. This can drastically degrade performance.

The [`@code_warntype`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-code-warntype) macro is very helpful for diagnosing this.

In our case, assuming that all columns are of the same type, a simple workaround is to copy the columns into a `Matrix` before calling the function. (The time this takes is negligible compared to the rest of the function.) To do so, we can specialize `ham` for the `DataFrame` type:

```
ham(df::DataFrame) = ham(convert(Matrix, df))
```

Note that the compiler specializes code for types at function boundaries, so it is important that this conversion takes place outside the original `ham` function. In particular, don't put the conversion into the original function like so:

```
# Don't do this!
function ham(x)
    df = convert(Matrix, x)
    [rest of ham...]
end
```

because the type of `x` here might not contain sufficient information to infer the type of `df`. Such is the case for `DataFrames`.

Julia documentation: [function barriers](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#kernel-functions).

---

**Simple benchmark**

After implementing these suggestions, the speedup on calculating the distance matrix for 128 vectors of 256 integers each is by about 1000x: (note that the times are in microseconds vs milliseconds)

```
using BenchmarkTools
using DataFrames
M = rand(0:1, 256, 128);
df = DataFrame(M);
tdf = DataFrame(permutedims(M)); # transpose rows and columns
```

```
julia> @benchmark ham($df)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  387.33 KiB
  allocs estimate:  133
  --------------
  minimum time:     493.841 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      537.689 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        610.732 μs (2.74% GC)
  maximum time:     6.215 ms (81.69% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          8176
  evals/sample:     1
```

```
julia> @benchmark hamjulia($tdf)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  128.08 KiB
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     538.585 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      546.390 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        551.220 ms (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     567.238 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10
  evals/sample:     1
```

The additional memory allocations in `ham` are due to the conversion of the `DataFrame` to a `Matrix`.

---

Edit, a year later, to add:

**4. Use multi-threading.**

Each distance is calculated independent of the other distances, so we can easily parallelize the code by annotating the outer loop with [`Threads.@threads`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/multi-threading/#Base.Threads.@threads), like so:

```
    Threads.@threads for j in 1:ncols
        for i in j+1:ncols
            [...]
        end
    end
```

You will have to run Julia with the `--threads auto` option to make use of multiple threads. This approximately halves the runtime of the benchmark on my quad-core machine.

Julia documentation: [multi-threading](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I will run some tests with it. I noticed that I don't need the `DataFrame` so much. What about only filling half of the distance matrix? Do you know how stop when we reached the diagonal? (the distance matrix is filled twice here)

Comment: No problem! The sample code already stops at the diagonal: notice that the outer loop goes `for j in 1:ncols, i in j+1:ncols`, where `i` depends on `j` and so excludes the diagonal and one half of the matrix. Hence the `A[i, j] = A[j, i] = v` sets each non-diagonal element exactly once.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. But your function still returns a full matrix right? Wouldn't save memory to only return the half matrix?

Comment: Yes, it returns a full matrix.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but it return the full matrix but only compute the half matrix. Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Only half the matrix is calculated but the entire matrix is filled because of the symmetric assignment `A[i, j] = A[j, i] = v`.

Comment: simply beautiful .....

Answer (score 3):

As a cheap first try I suggest [`Distances.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl) with (I think)

```
pairwise(Hamming(), df, dims=1)
```